# Is there a way to acknowledge a Google form submission automatically via reddit PM?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-apps-script, google-forms, reddit

I'm using a Google form to collect submissions from reddit users. One of the fields in my form is **reddit username**. When a user makes a submission, I want to automatically send the username that was filled in a reddit PM acknowledging their submission, e.g. a "thank you for filling in the form!" message.

**What is the easiest way to achieve this?**

My current line of thinking is that:

1. I will need a way to detect incoming submissions and send out that data to a Python reddit bot in some manner.
2. The reddit bot will receive this data, format a message, and PM the user.

For step 1, I am comfortable working with Google Apps script. I currently have a setup where I'm able to send out form submission data to a Discord webhook, but I don't know how to set up a similar system for reddit. Getting the data out to my Python script is the part I'm a bit stuck in.

Is this approach valid or should I be going about it differently? Any advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: The question is too broad for the site. But, you can use reddit api directly from apps-script. Receive>form submission> send a PM to reddit user using reddit api(You'll register a bot in reddit to work as your apps-script).

Comment: Hi @TheMaster thanks for your comment! I can't see where exactly I can use the reddit API directly from apps script, could you elaborate just a bit or point me in the right direction for that?

Comment: @Sidewinder [Reddit's API documentation](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/) has everything you need.

Comment: Are you already using `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)` to send out an HTTPS request?  That's how you'd connect to something external from Apps Script.

Comment: @Side Dimu and Sandy have provided excellent directions.

Comment: @SandyGood that's right, for Discord I am using `UrlFetchApp.fetch("DISCORD WEBHOOK URL", api_config)` and the form data gets posted in a Discord channel. Instead of the webhook URL here I need to pass it to my own Python script. Do you have a recommendation on how to set up the receiving end? e.g. [something like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38070665/5900486)

Comment: I don't know anything about Python or how you would set up the receiving end.  Where is your Python script?  On a server somewhere?

Comment: @side You must host your Python script somewhere, if you want to trigger it inside apps script. But, Like I said,  There's no need for Python. Post to reddit api directly  through UrlFetch

Comment: @TheMaster thanks, looking back I think that's the cleanest way to do it. I'll try that.

Comment: @SandyGood it would be on an external server yes, but some further reading shows I might not need the Python middleman at all, and I could make do with UrlFetch direct with reddit's API, which I'll explore further. Thank you for taking the time to respond!