# positional argument error when trying to send a post request

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to send a post request to a python backend running on a fast API server. The current method I am using below throws error `test() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given` but I haven't passed any arguments to the function `test`. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

```
import requests

data = {"foo": "bar"}

r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/test", json = data)

print(r.text)
```

```
import requests
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test(request):
    print(request.form['foo'])
    return 'thisIsResponse'
```

**EDIT:** as per John Gordon's answer I updated my code by assigning a positional argument to the test function now I get error `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 375, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/spree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 271, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/spree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 118, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/spree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/spree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/spree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 84, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/spree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/spree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/spree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/home/spree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/spree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 706, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/spree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/spree/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/home/spree/spreeTv/./ods_info.py", line 30, in test
    print(request.form['foo'])
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Have a look at [How to read body as any valid json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64379089/how-to-read-body-as-any-valid-json)

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED**

[Here's a canonical way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65114346/7732200) to get request body as any valid JSON in FastAPI.

If you want to stick to the current solution, there are two things to be changed:

- you're sending a JSON payload, not form data - use `request.json()` to get it
- however, `request.json()` returns a coroutine, so to use it, I'd recommend to mark your function as `async` (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658748/using-fastapi-in-a-sync-way-how-can-i-get-the-raw-body-of-a-post-request))

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
async def test(request):
    print(await request.json())
```

P.S.
Just a note: FastAPI relies on type annotations to determine which arguments to pass. So if you need `request` variable to be an actual request object, just let the framework know about this:) Though in this case it will pass a request object anyway.

```
from fastapi import Request

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test(request: Request):
    ...
```

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the actual problem, though a canonical way still works and I'd recommend it anyway:)

Answer (score 1):

> but I haven't passed any arguments to the function test

You aren't calling `test()` directly; the FastAPI framework calls it for you, automatically, when a matching web request is received.

And when it does, it passes one argument.  So the error is that you've defined `test()` to accept no arguments.

Change your definition to this:

```
def test(request):
```

(... where did you think `request.form` came from?)

Comment: I applied that now it throws error: ```TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: @seriously Are we supposed to guess where this error is?  Please update your question to include the full error trace message.

Comment: OK, apparently `request.form` is a function, and cannot be accessed the way you're trying to do it.  Where did you get that code?  Did you copy it as an example from somewhere?

Comment: yeah I got it from an SO post that had Flask running as a server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070373/how-to-send-and-receive-http-post-requests-in-python

Comment: Well, you're not using Flask here, you're using FastAPI.  Why would you use Flask code as an example?

Comment: I thought they had a similar request access structure. I figured wrong!